# template_preprocess_comment() overrides template.php

Tags: 7, theming

I try to override this function in my template.php in Drupal 7; I copied the function found on [template_preprocess_comment()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7).

The first line contains `function themename_preprocess_comment($variables)`.

It contains the following code, which doesn't work.

```
$variables['submitted'] = t('!username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['author'], '!datetime' => $variables['created']));
```

I clear the cache, I override `theme_textarea($variables)` and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variable by reference like this using &

```
function themename_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. See [garland_preprocess_comment()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes--garland--template.php/function/garland_preprocess_comment/7) for an example of comment preprocess function.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but why theme_textarea works already without the &?